# Counting Unique Customers in Categories Based on Call Log Status Hierarchy

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula

I have a table of call logs of customers. For the purposes of what I'm trying to do, the table only consists of Customer ID and Call Status. Each customer could have multiple entries with varied call statuses.

E.g table:

```
Customer    Status
1           Didn't Reach - No Voicemail
3           Left a Voicemail
2           Left a Voicemail
1           Left a Voicemail
1           Talked With Customer
3           Didn't Reach - No Voicemail
2           Talked With Customer
2           Left a Voicemail
2           Talked With Customer
```

My Output should be:

```
Status                      # of Customers
Talked With Customer        2
Left a Voicemail            1
Didn't Reach - No Voicemail 0
```

This is due to the fact that from the 3 different status their heirarchy is as follows:

```
1. Talked with Customer
2. Left a Voicemail
3. Didn't Reach - No Voicemail
```

A patient should only be counted in the highest category (1>2>3), which is why in my example, there are no customers in "Didn't reach - no voicemail" as all of them had AT LEAST a voicemail left.

Hopefully this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit question to show larger data sample and desired output. Do you have a table for the Status hierachy?

Comment: I'd probably do this in two steps.  (1) Translate the text descriptors into numbers the way you've defined them, perhaps in a new column, and (2) Apply `MINIFS`-- or if your version of Excel doesn't have it, use an equivalent array formula-- to find the lowest number for a given Customer ID.

Comment: If data is in Access table, why is Excel involved?

Comment: @June7 i edited it with an example + expected output. The reason I tagged Access because this is data exported from an Access table as an excel spreadsheet. There is no table for the hierarchy yet, but if needed I can create it within the spreadsheet.

Comment: Okay, but why export raw data to Excel and manipulate there? A query in Access should be able to produce this output.

Comment: @June7 Simply because that's just how I was handed the data and end result should be in an excel file. I do have access to the Access DB so I could make a query there and place the results in the excel spreadsheet if you'd be able to guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SQL statement can produce this output. Does require a table of status hierarchy if want to show all status even if there is no data for a status.

Can export query to Excel or Excel can link to query object. Or Excel VBA can connect to Access db and pull data with SQL statement to a recordset object and use CopyFromRecordset method to save data to worksheet range.

```
SELECT StatusHierarchy.StatusDesc, Count(Query1.Customer) AS CntStat
FROM (SELECT Customer, Min(StatusValue) AS MinOfStatusValue
      FROM StatusHierarchy 
      LEFT JOIN Table1 ON StatusHierarchy.StatusDesc = Table1.Status
      GROUP BY Table1.Customer) AS Query1 
RIGHT JOIN StatusHierarchy ON Query1.MinOfStatusValue = StatusHierarchy.StatusValue
GROUP BY StatusHierarchy.StatusDesc
ORDER BY Count(Query1.Customer) DESC;
```

Comment: Instead of saving status description into call log, really should save the status value, which is essentially the status ID.